# Migrate external content types from 2010 to 2013

Tags: external-content-type, bdc, bdc-model

I have done a test 2010 -> 2013 migration and most things work fine. I have some user profile property mappings to BDC models

I have restored the secure store, managed metadata, BDC services using the old databases, it all appears in CA without errors but when I run user profile sync it doesn't import any of the custom properties for user profiles

I opened SPD and went to Operations Design View for an external content type and when I try to expand the data source I get `The type name for the secure store provider is not valid. Could not load file or assembly microsoft.office.businessdata, version=14.0.0.0, Culuture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`

Any ideas why it would be missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you try to [export and import the BDC Model using SharePoint Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650431.aspx#SP14MigratingECTs_CreatedSPD)? Do you get the same error? Another thing to try is to create a new ECT to verify that your SSS and BDC works as expected.

Comment: Silly user error, in SPD I tried to connect to the SQL server with the service account for BDC, not the account that was set up in secure store to actually access the data